# gcc with openmp support for Amazon Linux?

Tags: gcc, amazon-ec2, xgboost, amazon-linux

I've launched a cluster using Amazon EMR and require gcc at least version 5 in order to compile XGBoost.

However, the default version of gcc that comes with Amazon Linux apparently does not support OpenMP for some reason.

So is there some way to install g++ > 5 on Amazon Linux so that it also supports OpenMP compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install Gcc 6.4 for this: `sudo yum install -y gcc64 gcc64-c++`